Calculating PCR (Program clock reference) in MPEG2 Transport stream
i am implementing transcoder and packager for abr protocols (HLS/DASH), and also udp mutlicast as output option. I am currently finishing multiplexing of mpeg 2 transport streams, but i do not really understand how should pcr work, how should I calculate it, I have pts/dts values, is there some formula to derive pcr from pts and/or dts? When i do tsdump from tsduck with ffmpeg output they have around +100ms PCR delay on PTS.
I found some calculations like this:
(int64_t) ((8.0 * (packetsWritten * TS_PACKET_LENGTH + offset) / tsMuxrate) * TS_CLOCK + 0.5) + pcrStart

But it does not match ffmpeg calculation. When i do like this:
base = (int64_t) packet->dts - (int64_t) (SYSTEM_CLOCK_FREQ_90kHz * 0.1);

It has +100ms delay from PTS. But it is hardcoded.
